# Quotient of $\mathbb R^n\rtimes O\left(n\right)$ by $\mathbb Z^n\rtimes D_8$

Tags: lie-groups, symmetry, semidirect-product, quotient-group

What is the coset space $\frac{\mathbb R^n\rtimes O\left(n\right)}{\mathbb Z^n\rtimes D_8}$ as a manifold? I saw a claim that it is the $n$-dimensional torus $\mathbb T^n=S^1\times\cdots\times S^1$? Here the semidirect product is formed using the obvious action of $O\left(n\right)$ on $\mathbb R^n$, and $D_8$ is the dihedral group with $8$ elements, that is the symmetry group of a square.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a fibre bundle with fibre $\mathbb{T}^n$ and base $SO(n)/C_4$.  The pull back of this bundle along the map $SO(n)\to SO(n)/C_4$ is the trivial bundle.

To see this note that an element of the coset space has the form $(v,A)$ for $A\in O(n), v\in \mathbb{R}^n$, where $(v,A)\sim(x+gv,gA)$, for any $x\in \mathbb{Z}^n$ and $g\in D_8$.  Thus without loss of generality we may take $A\in SO(n)$ and $v\in \mathbb{T}^n$.  However we still must identify $(v,A)\sim(gv,gA)$ for $g\in C_4$.  That is the coset space is $$(\mathbb{T}^n\times SO(n))/C_4.$$

Projecting onto the second factor (mod $C_4$) gives the fibre bundle map: $$p\colon (\mathbb{T}^n\times SO(n))/C_4 \to SO(n)/C_4.$$

If we take a path $\phi$ in $SO(n)$ from the identity to an element $g\in C_4$, and map this path into $SO(n)/C_4$, we get a loop $\gamma$.  This loop may be lifted to a homotopy from the identity map $$1\colon p^{-1}(e)\to p^{-1}(e),$$ to the homotopy sending $$((v,e),t)\mapsto (v,\phi(t)).$$Thus
$$((v,e),1)\mapsto (v,g)=(g^{-1}(v),e).$$
In other words the monodromy action of $\pi_1(SO(n)/C_4)$ is given by the natural action of $C_4$ on $\mathbb{T}^n$.

Comment: Thanks so much. Just to check if I completely understand, the same argument would go through for any discrete subgroup of $O\left(n\right)$ which contains $-I$ right? Also, if I have a discrete subgroup which doesn't contain $-I$, will I get the same result with $SO\left(n\right)$ replaced by $O\left(n\right)$?

Comment: Yes, as long as an element of determinant $-1$ is in the discrete group then the argument will be the same - though of course the discrete group must act on $\mathbb{Z}^n$, which is quite restrictive.    However $-I$ does not always have determinant $-1$.  In the $D_8$ case it is the reflection with diagonal entries $-1,1,1,\cdots,1$ which has determinant $-1$.  If no element of determinant -1 is in the discrete group, then the coset space will be two disjoint copies of the coset space $(\mathbb{R}^n\rtimes SO(n))/(\mathbb{Z}^n\rtimes G)$.

Comment: yes, ofcourse. That is what I meant by $-I$. I've been making a lot of errors today. My bad. I am also interested in the homotopy type of this space. Can you maybe make any calculations about that?

Comment: The homology and homotopy groups of $\mathbb{T}^n$ are easy to compute (the Betti numbers follow the $n$'th row of Pascal's triangle, and homotopy gps disappear above dimension $1$).  It should not be too hard to look up what is known about the homology and homotopy groups of $SO(n)$.  Note the homotopy groups of $SO(n)$ and $SO(n)/G$, agree above dimension $1$, for $G$ discrete.  For homology the group homology of $G$ may help.  Then to combine the base and fibre you can use the long exact sequence associated to a fibre bundle for homotopy groups, and the Serre spectral sequence for homology.